# Gulp: bulk add an array of tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm writing a set of gulp tasks that can be reused. Currently I receive the gulp object from the client and then I add each task inside of this instance.

I'm wondering if there is a way to send to Gulp an array of tasks object and then Gulp itself can take care of adding these items for me?

Receiving the Gulp object from the client sounds odd to me. What if it has a task that I should not have access to?

**Currently I have:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var opts = {};
require('_base.gulpfile.js')(gulp, opts);
```

**This is somehow what I'm looking for**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var opts = {};
var tasks = require('gulp-util-tasks')(opts);

gulp.addTasks(tasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can thiblnk of is to create a filecrequiring those modules and load that file.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you look for but something similar might solve your problem.

```
var gulp-util-tasks = function (options) {
  var start = Date.now();

  console.log('Start task' + options.taskName);

  gulp.src(options.source)
...
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.dest))
    .pipe(notify(function () {
      console.log('END task ' + options.taskName + ' in ' + (Date.now() - start) + 'ms');
    }));
}

var options = {
   taskName: "test",
   source: "..",
   dest: '...'
};

gulp.task('default', function () {
  var tasks = ['gulp-util-tasks', ...]
  for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      eval(tasks[i] + '(options)');
  }
});
```